# How to debug Symfony 4 with Xdebug + PhpStorm on WSL?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug, symfony4

I have a PHP7.1 + nginx setup on Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL).
I'm mentioning WSL, so that in PhpStorm Xdebug is configured as a remote debugger, which connects via port 9000. Still WSL and PhpStorm using the same physical files.

For Symfony 4 project I'm using it's built in web-server: `bin/console server:run`

I've managed to set up PhpStorm to accept Xdebug connections. When the connection is established it asks or file mappings. I would expect `index.php` to be asked for, but the file mapping requested is: 
`vendor/symfony/web-server-bundle/Resources/router.php`.

As said in the docs inside this file - this file implements rewrite rules for PHP built-in web server. Okay.

If I accept the mapping to this file - debugging starts at `router.php` goes a few lines further and than nothing else happens. It doesn't jump to my `public/index.php` or doesn't stop on any breakpoint.

**The question is** - how to configure Symfony 4 debugging with Xdebug?
Maybe it is something wrong with mappings or what?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not really... I quit wasting time on trying to figure that out and use dump() and var_dump() ((

Answer (score 0):

Through https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/override-server-path-mappings-dialog.html, you should extend your file mappings. Probably, `router.php` was used as it was the first entry point to be found - but through this first file, you can see the file structure that WSL uses.

So: opening the mapping dialog should give you router.php somewhere down the structure with a mapped path which is also somewhere in a deeper directory. If you add a mapping for your root folder with the same mapping than the one used for `router.php`, removing `vendor/symfony/web-server-bundle/Resources/router.php`, you should be done

Comment: I already have mappings manually set for `public/index.php` and for project root dir. The thing is, that when PhpStorm receives connection from Xdebug it opens a dialog which requires to provide a mapping to that `router.php`. It never reaches index.php

Comment: I haven't worked with Symfony's own server yet, but is index.php ever called then?

Comment: In `router.php` at last it is required like this: `require getenv('APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER') ?: 'index.php'`

Comment: And is this line called or is that only a callback? Try it by adding something like `die('Got here');` to index.php

Comment: No..... That would be something to think about. However the script continues, the page is rendered... Maybe router.php is not the entry point. still debugger chose it, and doesn't hit any other files..

Comment: Sorry, the `index.php` file is been hit. In previous comment I've put die() in `router.php` just before `require getenv('APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER') ?: 'index.php'`. And in `router.php` it exit before this line. So `index.php` should have been called elswhere...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a very similar issue, where it seems that after the initial break (First line of script), xdebug cannot continue walking through code.

PhpStorm 2017.3,
Mojave 10.14,
Symfony 4.2,
Xdebug 2.7.1

Try upgrading PhpStorm to 2018.3 - it was the difference for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall ssh on WSL first:

```
sudo apt remove openssh-server
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Edit **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, change *PasswordAuthentication* to *yes* and add your login user to the bottom of the file: *AllowUsers yourusername*

Save your changes and restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh --full-restart
```

More info here: https://www.illuminiastudios.com/dev-diaries/ssh-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

At the end set remote debugging config in PhpStorm: http://blog.spameri.cz/2017/04/20/phpstorm-wsl-php.html

**Remember to set proper directory mapping.** For PhpStorm your files are in C:/ProjectsDir/MyProject, but for xdebug it's /mnt/c/ProjectsDir/MyProject

Comment: You can just change the port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` instead.